# Reference to component, rendered in "app.component.html"

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have component, named `NavigationBar`, which is placed in `app.component.html`

```
<body>
<app-navigation-bar></app-navigation-bar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</body>
</html>
```

He have property, named `IsUserLogged`. When true - then render menu for logged, if not render menu with login option. Is this possible, to get access/reference to this component from another?
I have routed endpoint `/login` to `LoginFormComponent`. I need to change `IsUserLogged` in `NavigationBar`, to true, after success user login.

Answer (score 1):

There are differents options to get the same result.
I'm going to share you one of them.

First, you have to create a global service

AuthService.service.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthServiceService {

  private _sesionState: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;

  constructor() {
    this._sesionState = new BehaviorSubject(false)
   }

  public changeLoggedIn(isLoggedIn: boolean): void{
    this._sesionState.next(isLoggedIn);
  }

  public onLoggedInChanged(){
    return this._sesionState.asObservable();
  }

}
```

Then, for example in your loggedIn page.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor(private authService: AuthServiceService) {}


  public login(): void {
    // Your logic here
    // If gets a success login
    this.authService.changeLoggedIn(true);

  }
```

Finally in your navbarComponent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor(private authService: AuthServiceService) {}


  public getLoggedInUser(): void {
    this.authService.onLoggedInChanged().subscribe((loggedIn: boolean) => {
      // If(loggedIn) => 
    })

  }
```

In this case, we are using Subjects to share information around the app. It could be whatever you want, any kind of data type.
So, if you want to know more of the Subjects Potentially
I would recommend you [Subjects, BehaviorSubjects, ReplySubjects](https://betterprogramming.pub/subjects-replay-subjects-behavior-subjects-async-subjects-in-rxjs-476eb41e0faf)